# BufferedImage to BufferedImage Array, Tiles Disapear

Tags: java, bufferedimage

Alright Stackoverflow, you are my last line as of right now.

If you would take a look at the code and pictures below, you will notice there are two files that are promptly named

Tile.java

TileMap.java

For more information on these classes, Google "ForeignGuyMike Dragon Tale Tutorial Part 8" for the download file of this project.
I am as of right now taking his class for reading in tiles as it seems quite effective for my efforts. The reason for switching to a BufferedImage array is to allow animations with each tile, as of right now it does work with images containing more than 1 frame.

NOW for these two classes:
They are purposely setup NOT to animate through the image, just to merely show them breaking for this program and not incorporating my imaging animation function.

Here they are

Before Code/Imagery Breaks
[image]

```
public class TileMap {

// position
private double x;
private double y;

// bounds
private int xmin;
private int ymin;
private int xmax;
private int ymax;

private double tween;

// map
private int[][] map;
private int tileSize;
private int numRows;
private int numCols;
private int width;
private int height;

// tileset
private BufferedImage[] tileset;
private int numTilesAcross;
private Tile[][] tiles;

private Animation an;

// drawing
private int rowOffset;
private int colOffset;
private int numRowsToDraw;
private int numColsToDraw;

public TileMap(int tileSize) {
    this.tileSize = tileSize;
    numRowsToDraw = GamePanel.HEIGHT / tileSize + 2;
    numColsToDraw = GamePanel.WIDTH / tileSize + 2;
    tween = 0.07;
    an = new Animation();
}

public void loadTiles(BufferedImage[] s, int delay) {

    an.setDelay(delay);
    an.setFrames(s);

    try {

        tileset = s;

        numTilesAcross = tileset[0].getWidth() / tileSize;
        tiles = new Tile[2][numTilesAcross];

        BufferedImage[] subimage = new BufferedImage[s.length];
        for(int col = 0; col < numTilesAcross; col++) {
            subimage[0] = tileset[0].getSubimage(
                        col * tileSize,
                        0,
                        tileSize,
                        tileSize
                    );
            tiles[0][col] = new Tile(subimage[0], Tile.NORMAL);
            subimage[0] = tileset[0].getSubimage(
                        col * tileSize,
                        tileSize,
                        tileSize,
                        tileSize
                    );
            tiles[1][col] = new Tile(subimage[0], Tile.BLOCKED);
        }

    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public void loadMap(String s) {

    try {

        InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream(s);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(in)
                );

        numCols = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        numRows = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        map = new int[numRows][numCols];
        width = numCols * tileSize;
        height = numRows * tileSize;

        xmin = GamePanel.WIDTH - width;
        xmax = 0;
        ymin = GamePanel.HEIGHT - height;
        ymax = 0;

        String delims = "\\s+";
        for(int row = 0; row < numRows; row++) {
            String line = br.readLine();
            String[] tokens = line.split(delims);
            for(int col = 0; col < numCols; col++) {
                map[row][col] = Integer.parseInt(tokens[col]);
            }
        }

    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public int getTileSize() { return tileSize; }
public double getx() { return x; }
public double gety() { return y; }
public int getWidth() { return width; }
public int getHeight() { return height; }

public int getType(int row, int col) {
    int rc = map[row][col];
    int r = rc / numTilesAcross;
    int c = rc % numTilesAcross;
    return tiles[r][c].getType();
}

public void setTween(double d) { tween = d; }

public void setPosition(double x, double y) {

    this.x += (x - this.x) * tween;
    this.y += (y - this.y) * tween;

    fixBounds();

    colOffset = (int)-this.x / tileSize;
    rowOffset = (int)-this.y / tileSize;

}

private void fixBounds() {
    if(x < xmin) x = xmin;
    if(y < ymin) y = ymin;
    if(x > xmax) x = xmax;
    if(y > ymax) y = ymax;
}

public void update() {
    an.update();
}

public void draw(Graphics2D g) {

    for(
        int row = rowOffset;
        row < rowOffset + numRowsToDraw;
        row++) {

        if(row >= numRows) break;

        for(
            int col = colOffset;
            col < colOffset + numColsToDraw;
            col++) {

            if(col >= numCols) break;

            if(map[row][col] == 0) continue;

            int rc = map[row][col];
            int r = rc / numTilesAcross;
            int c = rc % numTilesAcross;

            g.drawImage(
                tiles[r][c].getImage(),
                (int)x + col * tileSize,
                (int)y + row * tileSize,
                null
            );

        }

    }

}

public class Tile {

private BufferedImage image;
private int type;

// tile types
public static final int NORMAL = 0;
public static final int BLOCKED = 1;

public Tile(BufferedImage image, int type) {
    this.image = image;
    this.type = type;
}

public BufferedImage getImage() { return image; }
public int getType() { return type; }
```

NOW Here is the code after implementing a change

Change Sets:

Tile.java

-Constructor Param's have changed from BufferedImage to BufferedImage[]

-BufferedImage image to BufferedImage[] image;

-getImage to getImage(int i) { return image[i]; }

TileMap.java

-Initialized subimage and set it to BufferedImage[s.length];

-Removed all subimage[0] to subimage

-getImage in draw is now getImage(0); // Hard coded it

After

[image]

```
public class TileMap {

// position
private double x;
private double y;

// bounds
private int xmin;
private int ymin;
private int xmax;
private int ymax;

private double tween;

// map
private int[][] map;
private int tileSize;
private int numRows;
private int numCols;
private int width;
private int height;

// tileset
private BufferedImage[] tileset;
private int numTilesAcross;
private Tile[][] tiles;

private Animation an;

// drawing
private int rowOffset;
private int colOffset;
private int numRowsToDraw;
private int numColsToDraw;

public TileMap(int tileSize) {
    this.tileSize = tileSize;
    numRowsToDraw = GamePanel.HEIGHT / tileSize + 2;
    numColsToDraw = GamePanel.WIDTH / tileSize + 2;
    tween = 0.07;
    an = new Animation();
}

public void loadTiles(BufferedImage[] s, int delay) {

    an.setDelay(delay);
    an.setFrames(s);

    try {

        tileset = s;

        numTilesAcross = tileset[0].getWidth() / tileSize;
        tiles = new Tile[2][numTilesAcross];

        BufferedImage[] subimage = new BufferedImage[s.length];
        for(int col = 0; col < numTilesAcross; col++) {
            subimage[0] = tileset[0].getSubimage(
                        col * tileSize,
                        0,
                        tileSize,
                        tileSize
                    );
            tiles[0][col] = new Tile(subimage, Tile.NORMAL);
            subimage[0] = tileset[0].getSubimage(
                        col * tileSize,
                        tileSize,
                        tileSize,
                        tileSize
                    );
            tiles[1][col] = new Tile(subimage, Tile.BLOCKED);
        }

    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public void loadMap(String s) {

    try {

        InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream(s);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(in)
                );

        numCols = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        numRows = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        map = new int[numRows][numCols];
        width = numCols * tileSize;
        height = numRows * tileSize;

        xmin = GamePanel.WIDTH - width;
        xmax = 0;
        ymin = GamePanel.HEIGHT - height;
        ymax = 0;

        String delims = "\\s+";
        for(int row = 0; row < numRows; row++) {
            String line = br.readLine();
            String[] tokens = line.split(delims);
            for(int col = 0; col < numCols; col++) {
                map[row][col] = Integer.parseInt(tokens[col]);
            }
        }

    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public int getTileSize() { return tileSize; }
public double getx() { return x; }
public double gety() { return y; }
public int getWidth() { return width; }
public int getHeight() { return height; }

public int getType(int row, int col) {
    int rc = map[row][col];
    int r = rc / numTilesAcross;
    int c = rc % numTilesAcross;
    return tiles[r][c].getType();
}

public void setTween(double d) { tween = d; }

public void setPosition(double x, double y) {

    this.x += (x - this.x) * tween;
    this.y += (y - this.y) * tween;

    fixBounds();

    colOffset = (int)-this.x / tileSize;
    rowOffset = (int)-this.y / tileSize;

}

private void fixBounds() {
    if(x < xmin) x = xmin;
    if(y < ymin) y = ymin;
    if(x > xmax) x = xmax;
    if(y > ymax) y = ymax;
}

public void update() {
    an.update();
}

public void draw(Graphics2D g) {

    for(
        int row = rowOffset;
        row < rowOffset + numRowsToDraw;
        row++) {

        if(row >= numRows) break;

        for(
            int col = colOffset;
            col < colOffset + numColsToDraw;
            col++) {

            if(col >= numCols) break;

            if(map[row][col] == 0) continue;

            int rc = map[row][col];
            int r = rc / numTilesAcross;
            int c = rc % numTilesAcross;

            g.drawImage(
                tiles[r][c].getImage(0), // hard code the image at 0
                (int)x + col * tileSize,
                (int)y + row * tileSize,
                null
            );

        }

    }

}

public class Tile {

private BufferedImage[] image;
private int type;

// tile types
public static final int NORMAL = 0;
public static final int BLOCKED = 1;

public Tile(BufferedImage[] image, int type) {
    this.image = image;
    this.type = type;
}

public BufferedImage getImage(int i) { return image[i]; }
public int getType() { return type; }
```

Comment: Not sure if this is *the* bug, this is too much code to test. But you are assigning `subimage[0]` two times inside the loop, *and* reusing the same array, passing it to multiple `Tiles`. This means that after your loop, *all tiles will contain the last subimage of the last tile*. Either create a new array for each iteration, or better yet, create a copy of the array in the `Tile` constructor.

Comment: I was thinking this exact same thing, it's happened before with an array list and setting it to a new String, I'll test this and let you know what happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone looking to know the answer, it's been solved.

The section

```
BufferedImage[] subimage = new BufferedImage[s.length];
    for(int col = 0; col < numTilesAcross; col++) {
        subimage[0] = tileset[0].getSubimage(
                    col * tileSize,
                    0,
                    tileSize,
                    tileSize
                );
        tiles[0][col] = new Tile(subimage, Tile.NORMAL);
        subimage[0] = tileset[0].getSubimage(
                    col * tileSize,
                    tileSize,
                    tileSize,
                    tileSize
                );
        tiles[1][col] = new Tile(subimage, Tile.BLOCKED);
    }
```

Was the culprit. Thanks to haraldk for the advice to test this issue and the fix is to simply place the subimage within the loop. Changing the contents constantly and using the same array was simply storing the last of it's contents throughout the entire array and thus, messing it up.

Updated Code Sample

```
    for(int col = 0; col < numTilesAcross; col++) {
        BufferedImage[] subimage = new BufferedImage[s.length];
        subimage[0] = tileset[0].getSubimage(
                    col * tileSize,
                    0,
                    tileSize,
                    tileSize
                );
        tiles[0][col] = new Tile(subimage, Tile.NORMAL);
        subimage[0] = tileset[0].getSubimage(
                    col * tileSize,
                    tileSize,
                    tileSize,
                    tileSize
                );
        tiles[1][col] = new Tile(subimage, Tile.BLOCKED);
    }
```